# Magento get chosen shipping and billing method address fields

Tags: magento, checkout

How can I get the choosen shipping and billing fields during checkout? (I want to show them in sidebars)

I use this in shipping.phtml but ofcourse that's just for the current 'address' (and I want to use it in methods.phtml and other pages)

```
$this->getAddress()->getFirstname()
```

So I assumed that this would work out...

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getShippingAddress()->getFirstname()
```

But it didn't, anybody has a tip?

Addition:
This one was helping me a lot, but I'm stuck :-S
[How do I get the shipping method the user has chosen during checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032936/how-do-i-get-the-shipping-method-the-user-has-chosen-during-checkout)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shipping and billing addresses are children of quote object. So something like this shall work:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getFirstname();
```

Comment: This works for frontend user but what about making order into admin ?