# Magento - PHP - How to get session current shipping method title

Tags: php, magento, session

This is code i use for getting current session shipping method code:

```
<?PHP echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod(); ?>
```

But this code is only giving me the current session shipping method code not the shipping title.

How can i get the current session shipping method title ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032936/how-do-i-get-the-shipping-method-the-user-has-chosen-during-checkout

Comment: Can you post an answer to my question ? I have seen that but it is not working. Post what you think i must use.

Answer (score 4):

You can get current session shipping method code & description by the following

**Getting shipping method code**

```
 <?php echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod(); ?>
```

**Getting shipping method description/title**

```
<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingDescription() ?>
```

Comment: Using observer how to get available shipping method? @Supravat M

Answer (score 0):

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingDescription();
```